# Too many PostgreSQL processes running (using Django to write to DB)

Tags: django, postgresql, apache2, connection

I'm using Django to write to a Postgres DB on my server. The server receives about 800 insert requests every 15 minutes. Recently when I run ps aux on the server this is the number of postgres processes I see:

```
postgres  5721  0.0  0.6 102380 27372 ?        Ss   Jan27   0:04 postgres: writer process                                                      
postgres  5722  0.0  0.0 102280  1684 ?        Ss   Jan27   0:01 postgres: wal writer process                                                  
postgres  5723  0.0  0.0 102416  1800 ?        Ss   Jan27   0:03 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                         
postgres  5724  0.0  0.0  73828  1480 ?        Ss   Jan27   0:12 postgres: stats collector process                                             
root      8621  0.0  0.2 107912  8736 ?        Ss   Jan27   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  8628  0.0  0.0 104444  3096 ?        S    Jan27   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  8629  0.0  0.0 104444  2908 ?        S    Jan27   0:00 /usr/sbin/fcgi-pm -k start
www-data  8630  0.0  0.0 105620  2976 ?        S    Jan27   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 29332  1.2  1.1 471932 47432 ?        Sl   18:45   0:08 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 29350  1.0  1.2 468712 49372 ?        Sl   18:45   0:07 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 29351  1.2  1.2 541820 51836 ?        Sl   18:45   0:08 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
postgres 29386  0.1  0.7 104932 31680 ?        Ss   18:45   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48450) INSERT                 
postgres 29401  0.1  0.7 104932 29784 ?        Ss   18:45   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48463) INSERT                 
postgres 29407  0.1  0.7 105060 29888 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48467) COMMIT                 
postgres 29408  0.1  0.7 104932 31852 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48468) INSERT                 
www-data 29409  1.2  1.0 467728 42204 ?        Sl   18:46   0:07 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
postgres 29428  0.1  0.7 105060 31972 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48470) COMMIT                 
postgres 29433  0.1  0.7 104932 31788 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48474) INSERT                 
postgres 29434  0.1  0.7 104932 31908 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48475) COMMIT                 
postgres 29435  0.1  0.7 104932 31836 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48476) COMMIT                 
postgres 29439  0.1  0.7 104932 31736 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48480) COMMIT                 
postgres 29440  0.1  0.7 105060 31352 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48481) COMMIT                 
postgres 29441  0.1  0.7 105056 31960 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48482) COMMIT                 
postgres 29443  0.1  0.7 104932 31248 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48484) COMMIT                 
postgres 29444  0.1  0.7 104932 31976 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48485) COMMIT                 
www-data 29445  1.0  1.0 470256 44348 ?        Sl   18:46   0:06 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
postgres 29487  0.1  0.7 104932 32012 ?        Ss   18:46   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48487) COMMIT                 
postgres 29489  0.1  0.7 105060 31480 ?        Ss   18:47   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48489) INSERT                 
postgres 29491  0.1  0.7 104932 31788 ?        Ss   18:47   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48490) INSERT                 
postgres 29492  0.1  0.7 104932 31944 ?        Ss   18:47   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48491) INSERT                 
postgres 29496  0.1  0.7 104932 31260 ?        Ss   18:47   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48493) COMMIT                 
postgres 29499  0.1  0.7 105056 32088 ?        Ss   18:47   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48495) COMMIT                 
postgres 29502  0.1  0.7 105060 31936 ?        Ss   18:47   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48497) INSERT                 
postgres 29506  0.1  0.7 104932 31916 ?        Ss   18:47   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48501) INSERT                 
postgres 29518  0.1  0.7 104932 31736 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48511) COMMIT                 
postgres 29523  0.1  0.7 104932 31524 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48512) INSERT                 
postgres 29525  0.1  0.6 104932 27776 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48514) COMMIT                 
postgres 29526  0.1  0.7 104932 30992 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48515) COMMIT                 
postgres 29531  0.1  0.7 104932 28992 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48516) INSERT                 
postgres 29532  0.1  0.7 104932 29792 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48517) COMMIT                 
postgres 29533  0.1  0.7 104932 30396 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48518) INSERT                 
postgres 29536  0.1  0.7 104932 31028 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48520) INSERT                 
postgres 29537  0.1  0.7 104932 29264 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48521) INSERT                 
postgres 29542  0.1  0.7 104932 29596 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48525) COMMIT                 
postgres 29543  0.1  0.7 104932 30560 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48526) COMMIT                 
postgres 29545  0.1  0.7 104932 30864 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48528) INSERT                 
postgres 29550  0.1  0.7 104932 30964 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48529) COMMIT                 
postgres 29552  0.1  0.7 104932 31012 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48530) COMMIT                 
postgres 29553  0.1  0.7 104932 31260 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48531) SELECT                 
postgres 29554  0.1  0.7 104932 30976 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48532) INSERT                 
postgres 29556  0.1  0.7 104932 30084 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48534) INSERT                 
postgres 29557  0.1  0.7 104932 30644 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48535) INSERT                 
postgres 29558  0.1  0.7 104932 30408 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48536) INSERT                 
postgres 29559  0.1  0.7 104932 30048 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48537) INSERT                 
postgres 29560  0.1  0.7 104932 30488 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48538) COMMIT                 
postgres 29561  0.1  0.7 104932 29840 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48539) INSERT                 
postgres 29562  0.1  0.7 104932 30616 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48540) COMMIT                 
postgres 29564  0.1  0.7 104932 30456 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48541) INSERT                 
postgres 29565  0.2  0.7 104932 30612 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48542) COMMIT                 
postgres 29566  0.2  0.7 104932 30512 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48543) INSERT                 
postgres 29567  0.2  0.7 104932 30964 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48544) INSERT                 
postgres 29568  0.2  0.7 104932 30460 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48545) INSERT                 
postgres 29569  0.2  0.7 104932 30684 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48546) INSERT                 
postgres 29571  0.2  0.7 104932 31188 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48548) COMMIT                 
postgres 29572  0.2  0.7 104932 31280 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48549) INSERT                 
postgres 29573  0.2  0.7 104932 30632 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48550) COMMIT                 
postgres 29574  0.2  0.7 104932 30784 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48551) INSERT                 
postgres 29575  0.2  0.7 104932 31060 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48552) INSERT                 
postgres 29576  0.2  0.7 104932 31064 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48553) COMMIT                 
postgres 29577  0.2  0.7 105008 31184 ?        Ss   18:49   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48554) INSERT                 
postgres 29578  0.2  0.7 105016 31168 ?        Ss   18:50   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48555) COMMIT                 
postgres 29579  0.2  0.7 105064 30632 ?        Ss   18:50   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48556) INSERT                 
postgres 29580  0.2  0.7 105016 31208 ?        Ss   18:50   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48557) COMMIT                 
postgres 29582  0.2  0.7 104932 31268 ?        Ss   18:50   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48559) COMMIT                 
postgres 29583  0.2  0.7 104936 31348 ?        Ss   18:50   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48560) COMMIT                 
postgres 29585  0.2  0.7 104932 31280 ?        Ss   18:50   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48561) COMMIT                 
postgres 29586  0.2  0.7 104936 31376 ?        Ds   18:50   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48562) COMMIT                 
www-data 29587  1.5  0.8 462216 35916 ?        Sl   18:50   0:05 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
postgres 29775  0.2  0.7 104932 30528 ?        Ss   18:51   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48722) INSERT                 
postgres 29776  0.2  0.7 104936 31180 ?        Ss   18:51   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48723) COMMIT                 
postgres 29777  0.2  0.7 104932 31292 ?        Ss   18:51   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48724) INSERT                 
postgres 29944  0.2  0.6 105016 28424 ?        Ss   18:51   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(48890) COMMIT                 
postgres 30128  0.3  0.7 104936 29836 ?        Ss   18:52   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49070) INSERT                 
postgres 30129  0.3  0.7 104932 29444 ?        Ss   18:52   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49071) INSERT                 
postgres 30225  0.3  0.7 104932 30020 ?        Ss   18:52   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49167) INSERT                 
postgres 30301  0.2  0.7 104932 28884 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49242) COMMIT                 
postgres 30302  0.2  0.6 104932 28136 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49243) COMMIT                 
postgres 30305  0.2  0.6 104936 28116 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49245) COMMIT                 
postgres 30307  0.2  0.7 104936 29852 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49247) COMMIT                 
postgres 30308  0.4  0.7 104932 30512 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49248) INSERT                 
postgres 30309  0.2  0.6 104936 28060 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49249) COMMIT                 
postgres 30312  0.3  0.7 104932 28440 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49252) COMMIT                 
postgres 30327  0.3  0.7 104932 29324 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49267) COMMIT                 
postgres 30328  0.3  0.6 104932 27984 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49268) COMMIT                 
postgres 30375  0.3  0.7 104936 28912 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49314) COMMIT                 
postgres 30378  0.3  0.6 104936 27128 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49317) COMMIT                 
postgres 30381  0.3  0.6 104936 26372 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49320) COMMIT                 
postgres 30384  0.3  0.6 104932 27720 ?        Ss   18:54   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49323) COMMIT                 
postgres 30385  0.2  0.6 104416 26980 ?        Ss   18:54   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49324) COMMIT                 
postgres 30386  0.2  0.6 104416 27104 ?        Ss   18:54   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49325) INSERT                 
postgres 30387  0.2  0.6 104364 28160 ?        Ss   18:54   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49326) COMMIT                 
postgres 30389  0.2  0.6 104416 27496 ?        Ss   18:54   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49327) INSERT                 
postgres 30391  0.2  0.6 104396 27688 ?        Ss   18:54   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49329) COMMIT                 
postgres 30392  0.2  0.6 104416 28252 ?        Ss   18:54   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49330) COMMIT                 
postgres 30393  0.2  0.6 104420 28072 ?        Ss   18:54   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49331) COMMIT                 
postgres 30394  0.2  0.6 104416 28156 ?        Ss   18:54   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49332) COMMIT                 
postgres 30439  0.2  0.7 104420 28504 ?        Ss   18:54   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49377) INSERT                 
postgres 30658  0.0  0.2 104416  8316 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49596) COMMIT                 
postgres 30896  0.0  0.1 104336  7688 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49830) COMMIT                 
postgres 30946  0.0  0.1 104220  7272 ?        Ss   18:56   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(49880) COMMIT                 
postgres 31073  2.5  0.6 104268 25816 ?        Ss   18:56   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(50006) SELECT                 
1000     31104  0.2  0.0  19296  2068 pts/0    Ss   18:56   0:00 -bash
1000     31134  0.0  0.0  16332  1136 pts/0    R+   18:56   0:00 ps aux
postgres 31135  0.0  0.1 103960  4380 ?        Rs   18:56   0:00 postgres: abs ap 127.0.0.1(50057) startup
```

It seems like I'm losing a lot of inserts because that many processes are running. Very often I see the message:

> psql: FATAL:  connection limit exceeded for non-superusers

Any ideas on what might be going wrong? Why are the processes active for so long?

Comment: Do you open a new connection for each and every new INSERT statement?

Comment: Yes. Can you maybe post a link on how I can group several INSERTs into one transaction using Django?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your storage can't process that many transactions. A postgres process with PID 29586 is currently waiting for a device to complete a request (it is in a "D" state, which means "uninterruptable sleep (usually IO)") and is probably blocking other requests. Is it a virtual machine — for example a VPS? They often have not very responsive IO — especially for a lot of [`fsync` requests](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) (every commit generates a `fsync` in default Postgres configuration).

If you can afford to loose some confirmed transactions in case of a crash then you can make it much faster and less dependent on IO latency by turning off `synchronous_commit` in `postgresql.conf` or just for these transactions.

Also this can be made much faster if you can make your writes to run in one transaction instead of many.

Answer (score 1):

Could you put the inserts inside a [bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create)?

```
to_insert = []

for item in items:
    to_insert.append(ObjectModel(item=item))

ObjectModel.objects.bulk_create(to_insert)
```

It would help if you are creating new connections as mentioned by @cyroxx.

Answer (score 0):

The Error message

> FATAL: connection limit exceeded for non-superusers

is an unambiguous pointer to the setting [**`max_connections`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS)

Set a higher limit in `postgresql.conf` (and restart the postgres server process). Something like:

```
max_connections = 200
```

Or what ever you need to satisfy the requests. Be advised that needs some resources. [More info in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/kernel-resources.html#SYSVIPC)

Ideally, you would not need a setting that high and spread out those `INSERT` requests or bundle them into a single (or few) connections. Possibly even into a single `INSERT` command.

Might also be worth to check if you have [autocommit on in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#autocommit-mode):

```
DATABASE_OPTIONS = {
    "autocommit": True,
}
```

If not, you need to send `COMMIT` at the end of a transaction.